# array intersection in php

Tags: php, html

i have this snippet:

```
$tableau = array_intersect(GetSearchByRegion($_SESSION['region']),
                       GetSearchByCity($_SESSION['city']),
                       GetSearchByState($_SESSION['state']),
                       GetSearchByCountry($_SESSION['country']),
                       GetSearchByKeywords($_SESSION['keywords']),
                       GetSearchByDate($_SESSION['date']),
                       GetSearchByCompany($_SESSION['company']),
                       GetSearchByCategory($_SESSION['category']));

if(sizeof($tableau) == 0)
{
    header('Location: fail.html');
}
else
{    
    $tableau1 = array_intersect(GetSearchByRegion($_SESSION['region']),
                            GetSearchByState($_SESSION['state']));

    echo "size of state =".sizeof(GetSearchByState($_SESSION['state']))."</br>";
    echo "size total".sizeof($tableau)."</br>";
    echo sizeof($tableau1)."</br>";

    // $_SESSION['liste'] =GetInformationsFromId($tableau);
    // header('Location: list.php');
}
```

the problem is the result is `size of state =1
size total3
3`
i don't know why the intersection didn't work: a table with a size=1 inter another table the result normally is a table that it size is au max equal to one.so:

- i need to know what is the error
- and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Array_intersect() doesn't eliminate duplicates:

```
php > $x = array('a', 'a', 'b', 'c');
php > $y = array('a', 'b');
php > var_dump(array_intersect($x, $y));
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "b"
}
php >
```

note the duplicated `a` value in the `$x` array. Only two distinct values in common between the two, and only two values in `$y`, but the intersection is still 3 values.

Comment: but one of my tables contains one row and the other has no row duplicated (from DB with primary Key) so this problem of duplication is not the cause

Comment: well, dump out your $tableau and $tableau1 to see what you're working with. dealing with the counts only is somewhat pointless.

Comment: `array_unique(array_intersect($x, $y))` gives me always as result one row

Comment: the result of `echo var_dump(tableau)."</br>";
       echo var_dump(tableau1)."</br>"; ` is `string 'tableau' (length=7)

string 'tableau1' (length=8)`

Comment: beats me how you could be getting size=3, then, since there's only one element in each.

Answer (score 0):

this is the result:
`

```
table state =
array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string '2013-01-01' (length=10)
      'date' => string '2013-01-01' (length=10)
      2 => string 'software engineer' (length=17)
      'title' => string 'software engineer' (length=17)
      3 => string 'wall street' (length=11)
      'state' => string 'wall street' (length=11)
      4 => string 'Newyork' (length=7)
      'city' => string 'Newyork' (length=7)
      5 => string 'alaska' (length=6)
      'region' => string 'alaska' (length=6)
      6 => string 'quality' (length=7)
      'company_name' => string 'quality' (length=7)
table total=
array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string '2013-01-01' (length=10)
      'date' => string '2013-01-01' (length=10)
      2 => string 'software engineer' (length=17)
      'title' => string 'software engineer' (length=17)
      3 => string 'wall street' (length=11)
      'state' => string 'wall street' (length=11)
      4 => string 'Newyork' (length=7)
      'city' => string 'Newyork' (length=7)
      5 => string 'alaska' (length=6)
      'region' => string 'alaska' (length=6)
      6 => string 'quality' (length=7)
      'company_name' => string 'quality' (length=7)
  1 => 
    array
      0 => string '2' (length=1)
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      1 => string '2013-01-08' (length=10)
      'date' => string '2013-01-08' (length=10)
      2 => string 'formater' (length=8)
      'title' => string 'formater' (length=8)
      3 => string 'erer' (length=4)
      'state' => string 'erer' (length=4)
      4 => string 'vvv' (length=3)
      'city' => string 'vvv' (length=3)
      5 => string 'colorado' (length=8)
      'region' => string 'colorado' (length=8)
      6 => string 'quality' (length=7)
      'company_name' => string 'quality' (length=7)
  2 => 
    array
      0 => string '3' (length=1)
      'id' => string '3' (length=1)
      1 => string '2013-01-08' (length=10)
      'date' => string '2013-01-08' (length=10)
      2 => string 'hardware engineer' (length=17)
      'title' => string 'hardware engineer' (length=17)
      3 => string 'rgjjer' (length=6)
      'state' => string 'rgjjer' (length=6)
      4 => string 'kjrg' (length=4)
      'city' => string 'kjrg' (length=4)
      5 => string 'oklahoma' (length=8)
      'region' => string 'oklahoma' (length=8)
      6 => string 'quality' (length=7)
      'company_name' => string 'quality' (length=7)

table small=
array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string '2013-01-01' (length=10)
      'date' => string '2013-01-01' (length=10)
      2 => string 'software engineer' (length=17)
      'title' => string 'software engineer' (length=17)
      3 => string 'wall street' (length=11)
      'state' => string 'wall street' (length=11)
      4 => string 'Newyork' (length=7)
      'city' => string 'Newyork' (length=7)
      5 => string 'alaska' (length=6)
      'region' => string 'alaska' (length=6)
      6 => string 'quality' (length=7)
      'company_name' => string 'quality' (length=7)
  1 => 
    array
      0 => string '2' (length=1)
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      1 => string '2013-01-08' (length=10)
      'date' => string '2013-01-08' (length=10)
      2 => string 'formater' (length=8)
      'title' => string 'formater' (length=8)
      3 => string 'erer' (length=4)
      'state' => string 'erer' (length=4)
      4 => string 'vvv' (length=3)
      'city' => string 'vvv' (length=3)
      5 => string 'colorado' (length=8)
      'region' => string 'colorado' (length=8)
      6 => string 'quality' (length=7)
      'company_name' => string 'quality' (length=7)
  2 => 
    array
      0 => string '3' (length=1)
      'id' => string '3' (length=1)
      1 => string '2013-01-08' (length=10)
      'date' => string '2013-01-08' (length=10)
      2 => string 'hardware engineer' (length=17)
      'title' => string 'hardware engineer' (length=17)
      3 => string 'rgjjer' (length=6)
      'state' => string 'rgjjer' (length=6)
      4 => string 'kjrg' (length=4)
      'city' => string 'kjrg' (length=4)
      5 => string 'oklahoma' (length=8)
      'region' => string 'oklahoma' (length=8)
      6 => string 'quality' (length=7)
      'company_name' => string 'quality' (length=7)
```

`

Comment: why is the result is false?